# Drupal 7, Is there a module that detects file structure changes?

Tags: 7, security

Recently one of my clients sites was hacked and hackers uploaded a few directories and files into the web root folder.

I'm looking for a module or a method that has the ability detect file structure changes in the web root of drupal and any sub folder. In the end I want it to be able to email me when files get added or directories get made.

Comment: That isn't something the web app should be responsible for really - it should be implemented outside of Drupal by responding to file system events. The only option would be to continually run cron jobs that test every folder against a 'known good' version. Very expensive. And from a technical standpoint, how are you going to distinguish (for example) files in sites/default/files that were created by Drupal, and those that were created by a hack?

Comment: yea but this is just for a small site with very little traffic. yes its true that its unnecessary load on having drupal make the check on every cron run, but im looking for a quick solution without much fiddling around on the server side. and this would be ideal for the less tech savvy.

Answer (score 5):

There is quite a few:

- https://drupal.org/project/md5check (7.x.1.0 - actively maintained)
- https://drupal.org/project/hacked (7.x.2.0-beta -seeking new maintainer)
- https://drupal.org/project/sentry_server (6.x.1.x-dev -  seeking co-maintainer)
- https://drupal.org/project/file_integrity (abandoned)

I've included those abandoned and seeking new maintainers, in case you want to revive them or use them as starting points for your own project.

However, as noted by *Clive*, this is easier to set up and maintain outsite of Drupal.  Here  is a broad outline of what you need:

First, recursively run through every file and sub-folder on the server within the current directory of the script and generate a file containong the "master" hash for each.  Repeat this whenever you update your site by installing new modules, etc. or updating old ones.

Create a script (in your favourite scripting language) to do the following, and activate it with cron at regular intervals. Make sure that it is not remorely executable (store it outside the web root).

1. Load configuration file (list of files to exclude from scan, etc.)
2. Recursively run through every file and sub-folder on the server within the current directory of the script.
3. Generate a hash for each file and compare with the master hash
4. Alert (e.g. by email) if different.

Based on: [How to detect if your webserver is hacked and get alerted](https://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-detect-if-your-webserver-is-hacked-and-get-alerted/). They also have a script (*WebsiteCDS*) that does this taht you can download.  I haven't used it, and can't vouch for the quality of their code.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using [git](http://git-scm.com/) for that task.

Simple way is to:

```sh
cd /whatever/your/drupal/directory/is
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

Then, in system's CRON, add

```sh
git add . #To add files that appeared in the meantime
git commit -a -m 'Nightly commit' # -a to  automatically stage files
                                  # that have been modified and deleted
```

And you're done. You might need to investigate `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` options to make git work in scripts, but it's not hard.

That's it. It will scan, record changes, and to add to that, it will allow you to rollback whatever you need to have rolled back, if something will go awry. And you can use git hooks to mail you the list of changes. It is described in many places, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552360/git-push-email-notification) and [here](http://www.fclose.com/1473/setting-up-git-commit-email-notification/) - but this is a bit out of the scope of Drupal Answers.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr nope, just lazy ;)

Comment: Don't you need a -a on the nightly call to along with the commit?

Comment: @MPD you got the point. When I was simplifying my real setup for this answer, i oversimplified it. Corrected.